# Remove array from a multidimensional array based on a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

My multidimensional array is :

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [processId] => H5-05848939 
    [productCode] => ITBYMZ 
    [availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation 
    [totalPrice] => 27 
    [packagingType] => Box 
                        ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [processId] => H5-05848939 
    [productCode] => ITOLDZ 
    [availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation 
    [totalPrice] => 37 
    [packagingType] => Box 
                        ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [processId] => H5-05848939 
    [productCode] => IYDYMZ 
    [availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation 
    [totalPrice] => 37 
    [packagingType] => Bulk 
                        ) 
 )
```

And i have a SQL Database that contains almost all the products images.
I need to remove from the above array all the products that does not have an image.

I query the sql db with below code:

```
for ($n = 0; $n < 60; $n++) {
    $productc= $productCodes[$n];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ImageURL FROM Flat_table where ProductCode= '$productc'", $link);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ImageURL[$n] = $row["ImageURL"];
    }
}
```

Have any ideea how can i do this :
*I need to remove from the above array all the products that does not have an image.*

Comment: whats the origin of the multi dimensional array? from DB too? why not just straight up query those entries that does have an image url

Comment: @Ghost its SOAP response

Comment: if its not that many, well you could, query each element and check, and no need to the while loop if each code is unique

Comment: @Ghost that is just an example with 3 products, the main response has over 1000 records.

Comment: use the idea below, could be done also in that way, filter all the way thru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first just pull all the product codes that don't have an image like:

```
SELECT f.ProductCode FROM Flat_table f WHERE f.ImageURL IS NULL
```

Note if your fields are not `NULL` when empty but something like `0` or and empty string then you'll need to adjust that query. After you have all those id's in an array (loop over the result and make an array like `Array('IYDYMZ', 'ITOLDZ')`) you can just use array filter on the array of product objects:

```
$filtered = array_filter($arr, function ($a) use ($noImageIds) {
    return !(in_array($a->productCode, $noImageIds));
});
```

Also you should really use PDO or mysqli, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so for PDO a complete solution might look like:

```
// our array from the api is called $products
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT f.ProductCode FROM Flat_table f WHERE f.ImageURL IS NULL');
    $stmt->execute();

    $noImageProducts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    $filteredProducts = array_filter($products, function ($a) use ($noImageProducts) {
        // returning true means "keep", while false means omit
        // if the productCode is in the array it doesn't have an image
        return !(in_array($a->productCode, $noImageProducts));
    });

} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I added some basic error checking. You shouldnt get that error unless `$db->prepare()` fails to prepare the query, but then you should get it as soon as `$stmt->execute()` since `$stmt` would be false...

Comment: I did manage to fix the error ( some misstyped vars ) But always the $noImageHotels is empty I dont see where the array is created.,